# Data Transfer from S3 to BigQuery every hour

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I want to transfer data from S3 to BigQuery every hour. I was thinking of the [BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Amazon S3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer#console), but its scheduled execution is limited by 24 hour. I'm trying to use `Embulk` and learning how to use it now. However I want to know better method to achieve data transfer if it exists. Could you give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery Data Transfer service's schedules execution is not limited to 24 hours. You can use custom schedule option to to do transfer at any interval. For every two hours you can use `every 02:00`. But be aware of its other limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer-intro?hl=en_US#quotas_and_limits).
[image: Transfer Config Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to use custom schedule.

Comment: This does not seem to work (anymore?). It gives me error "The specified schedule is invalid: [every 02:00]"